# Automated Directory symlink

Tags: powershell, symbolic-link

I have a situation with Autodesk Revit that Autodesk recommends "fixing" with SymLinks as outlined [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-cloud-worksharing-forum/hard-disk-when-use-c4r/td-p/6494036). However, as mentioned in that thread, this manual approach falls apart when you have hundreds of machines across multiple offices to address (pretty common in Architecture and Engineering firms).
The main issue is that mklink must be run elevated, but users are standard users, not local administrators. I guess I COULD create a dedicated user just for this purpose, lock them out of the entire network, and then safely have the user name and password as clear text in a PowerShell script that I could run elevated with that account to do the link creation. But is that the right/best answer? Or is there some less... kludgy... option?
I did find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10), which suggests an option is to use group policy to allow users to create symlinks, but I assume this is not default behavior for a reason. And I can't decide which is worse, storing the password to an intentionally gimped user account as clear text, or enabling symlinks for all users. Neither sounds like a great idea. Of course if Autodesk wasn't stupid we wouldn't have this problem, but they are, and we do.